# check for internet connection in PhoneGap for all platform?

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

this is for two days I am searching for how to detect the internet connection in phonegap using my chrome browser, then I checked many answers on Stack and google but unfortunatly I couldn't find any perfect answer, now I want to ask directly here how can I check the internet connection in phongegap using dreamwaever with windows 8 , is there any way to do this, in addition I want to test on chrome browser then convert it to apps on Adobe eng. Thanks for any help.

I faced these errors without any alert:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use cordova plugin :

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
```

then for checking the connection:

```
function checkConnection() {
  var objConnection = navigator.network.connection;
  if (objConnection.type == Connection.NONE) {
    //Do somthing 
  }

}
```

for more details about the cordova network plugin and the connection types : [cordova-plugin-network](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Hope this help.

***Update***

lets say that you want to check the connection on device ready event:

Register **checkconnection** function to **deviceready** event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkConnection, false);
```

check the connection if there is no connection **for example** :show him a message 
or do whatever action you want :

```
function checkConnection() {
      var objConnection = navigator.network.connection;
      if (objConnection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        alert("Please check your network connection"); 
      }

    }
```

***Note:***
You can replace or use any other phone gap event to check the connection like "offline" event.
 So if you regiter the **checkconnction** function to **offline** event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", checkConnection, false);
```

the alert message will be shown to user if he lost the connection.

for more info about Cordova lifecycle events please check [cordova events](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html)

Comment: How to use this I found many answers like this but I don't know how to use it

Comment: can you please provide me your code sample and i will inject "checkConnection" into it

Comment: this is my code in mediafire check index.html (  https://www.mediafire.com/?bh08qyaqw1h2dp2 )

Comment: firstable I don't understand what do you mean but, I wanna check for internet connection available or not then I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Sorry Amr it's not working yet I put your code I faced the same issue not working (Uncaught ReferenceError: connectionType is not defined )

Comment: ok . could you please comment this part in your code @ index.html

Comment: Sorry I was wrong I didn't delete my previous code there was two Evenlisner , and I don't have any error but the event not fired for the this code:


`document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkConnection, false);

      function checkConnection() {
      var objConnection = navigator.network.connection;
      if (objConnection.type == Connection.NONE) {
         alert("Please check your network connection"); 
      }
   else{
    alert(2);
   }

    }`

Comment: but for make a sure I am testing on chrome browser not on real device

Comment: that is the reason . i think the cordova events will fire only if the app is running on real device or at least inside emulator like [Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en)

Comment: just let me test on my real device

Comment: I test on webMatrix I didn't get any alert , then I checked on my chrome browser <body onload="checkConnection"></body>

I got this error(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined )

Comment: to test it, please try this on real device or use Ripple.

Comment: please check my update I faced these errors on ripple but there is no alert for your if statement

Comment: Can you test it on real device ?

Comment: Sorry Can you give me your email or fb or viber or whatsApp to share with you directly ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65094/discussion-between-amr-bahaa-and-ror).

Comment: What if I get only 'Unknown' returned for type and not something like 'Connection.NONE' etc ... ?